# Regarding an inverse trigonometric equation.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I tried to find the solutions of this equation
$$
\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)+\text{arccot}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{2x}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{3}
$$
I got solutions $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $-\sqrt3$. by reciprocating the arc cot term into arc tan term, adding both and solving the equation. But in solutions, in addition to above answers, $\sqrt3+2$ and $\sqrt3-2$ has also been given as answers, which I cannot figure out how they came?

Comment: You can add how you got these. And use \$...\$ instead of (/.../)

Comment: WolframAlpha has the same result as you: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28+%5Cfrac%7B2x%7D%7B1-x%5E2%7D+%29%2Barccot%28%5Cfrac%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7B2x%7D%29%3D%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7B3%7D

Comment: It looks like they are using $ \ - \frac{\pi}{6} \ $ as one of the angles (tangent value $ \ - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \ $ ) and are taking the arccotangent value as $ \ \frac{5 \pi}{6} \ $ .  Sources I've checked differ on what the range for arccotangent is: some (like WA) show $ \ \ -\frac{\pi}{2} \ < \ \theta \ < \ 0 \ \ , \ \ 0 \ < \ \theta \ \le \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ ; others give $ \ 0 < \ \theta \ < \ \pi \ $ . (This may be why Maple and Mathematica disagree on admissible solutions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that:
$\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)+\text{arccot}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{2x}\right)$=\begin{cases}
2\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right),  & \text{if $\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)$$\gt$$0$} \\
2\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)+\pi, & \text{if $\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)$ $\lt$$0$}
\end{cases}. 
In the first case, you get x=1/$\sqrt3$,x=-$\sqrt3$.
In the second case, you get x=$\sqrt3$+2,$\sqrt3$-2.
P.S.  I am using principal values for all inverse trigonometric ratios involved in here.

Comment: How $2\arctan(\cdots)+\pi$?

Comment: yes ,correct! just replace the (....) by say ,y and then you'll see that: arctan(1/y) +\pi=arccot(y)  if y is negative.

Comment: I may provide you its proof,if you wish.I am new to this site so I don't know how to type these bigger brackets... etc. etc!

Comment: Please show how.

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$...

Comment: Suppose, y=-z, (z is positive ),then arccot(y)=arccot(-z)=\pi -arccot(z)       Now you might be knowing :arccot(z)=arctan(1/z) for positive z,hence  arccot(-z)=\pi - arctanz.Now substitue z=-y,and you get the result.

Comment: How $\cot^{-1}(-z)=\pi-\cot^{-1}z$?

Comment: Let z=cot(thta), 0<thta<pi[principal branch of cot].So -z=cot(pi-thta) , Note that pi- thta is also in between 0 and pi. So you can define arccot(-z) ,which in this case will be: pi -thta, Now put thta=arccot(z)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

Let $\cot^{-1}x=\theta$ 
$x=\cot\theta$ 
$$\boxed{\tan^{-1}\frac1x=\theta}$$ 
$$\boxed{\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1-xy}} \ \ \text{(Not necessarily used)}$$
So $$\cot^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{2x}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$
$$\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=\frac{\pi}3$$
$$\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=\sqrt3$$
$$2x=\sqrt3-\sqrt3x^2$$

Comment: I used this process and got the above answers but what about the rest two?

Comment: I don't think they are right, check WA. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%7B%5Cfrac%7B2x%7D%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7D%2Barccot%7B%5Cfrac%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7B2x%7D%7D%3Bx%3D%5Csqrt3%2B2

Comment: Maple confirms $2+\sqrt{3}$ and $-2+\sqrt{3}$ are solutions: see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9n2zrmvf3s0zad/sol.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: Then why is WA showing that?

Comment: @ Aditya Agarwal : Read the last comment to the question.

Comment: So what?  . . . . . .

Comment: WA uses a different definition of the range of arccotangent from many other sources.  So the second solution is inadmissible for WA, but fine for others.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Answer revised (explaining the difference in results) in light of comments. (And I really can't take credit for this, as it was other people who pointed out the variation in the definition of the inverse trigonometric functions.)

If you try this on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot%28x%29), for example, it will plot the arc cotangent function like this:

[image: inverse cotangent graph with two branches]

Therefore if you try substituting either the "solution" $\sqrt 3 + 2$ for $x$ in $\text{arccot}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{2x}\right)$, [Wolfram Alpha evaluates it as $-\frac\pi6$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot%28%281-x%5E2%29%2F%282x%29%29+where+x+%3D+2%2Bsqrt%283%29).
You will [get the same result if you substitute $\sqrt 3 - 2$
for $x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot%28%281-x%5E2%29%2F%282x%29%29+where+x+%3D+-2%2Bsqrt%283%29).

This explains why one might reasonably not see $x = \sqrt3 \pm 2$
as a solution of the equation.

But evidently the person writing the answer key for this problem takes the definition of the arc cotangent function that has $\frac\pi2<\cot^{-1}(x)<\pi$
for all $x < 0$, as do many other people (a definition that is reflected in various mathematical software tools).
In that case the arc cotangent term in the question evaluates to $\frac56\pi$
rather than $-\frac\pi6$
when $x = \sqrt3 \pm 2$, thereby solving the equation.

Comment: Maple confirms $2+\sqrt{3}$ and $−2+\sqrt{3}$ are solutions: see https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9n2zrmvf3s0zad/sol.pdf?dl=0